# obj.authors.all() doesn't show anything

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I'm trying to make a django site in the latest version of django, but when i use the obj.authors.all() it returns nothing.

I have tried getting rid of the all() but returns empty Queryset.

**views.py**

```
 def menu(request):
        obj = Book.objects.get(id=1)
        obj = obj.authors.all()
    else:
        obj=""
    return render(request, 'menu.html', 
 {'obj':obj,'numautgors':authors})
```

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    text = models.TextField(unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('model-detail-view', args=[str(self.id)])
```

I expect it to return the authors, but it returns nothing.
Sorry if a duplicate. And one more question can i show all book written by a specific author or in this case User?

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
Books.objects.all().values('authors')
```

And suppose you want to show a book written by specific author then in that case your query should be :

```
Books.objects.filter(authors__username=request.user.username)
```

also you can use `get` based on your scenario

Taking assumption that your `User` model has username field.

Comment: but it returns in the first code <QuerySet [{'authors': None}, {'authors': None}]> and in the second <QuerySet []>

Answer (score 0):

I think you are sending the wrong context, so try like this:

```
def menu(request):
        obj = Book.objects.get(id=1)
        authors = obj.authors.all()
        return render(request, 'menu.html', {'obj':obj,'numautgors':authors})
```

Alternatively you can show the authors in template directly(you don't need to pass authors to template with context at all):

```
{% for author in obj.authors.all %}
    {{ author.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your variables

Firstly with

```
obj = Book.objects.get(id=1)
```

You are assigning the Book object retrieven from the database to the obj variable.

Then with

```
obj = obj.authors.all()
```

You assign authors to obj again, and then you are returning authors, a variable that does not exist.
Your naming seems confusing.
If you want the authors of the book with id 1, you could do this:

```
authors = Book.objects.filter(id=1).authors.all()
```

Comment: It returns an empty queryset

Comment: do you have authors associated with the book?

Comment: what do you mean